# Switch(master on/off) inside android:actionLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, submenu

I need to add master on/off (switch) as a sub menu in settings. I used separate layout xml and add it to menu.xml as android:actionLayout. But instead  of switch it display a blank line. The switch is not displaying there. This is the code I used. 
main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Menu"
        />
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/myswtich"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"/>

</menu>
```

switch_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchForActionBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here if I changed as android:showAsAction="always" in menu.xml that switch displays in action bar. But what I want is to display it in sub menu. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Action Layouts only exist on the Action Bar (i.e., items that are shown on the Action Bar such as via `showAsAction="ifRoom"` (assuming there is room) or `showAsAction="always"`). If can utilize [checkable Menu Items](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#checkable) for submenus that need to be toggleable.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that before. Do you have any idea  to get them into sub menu?

Comment: Besides replacing your switch with a checkable Menu Item as I suggested? No.

Comment: ah! no. It is not possible. I have to use switches there.

Comment: That (showing a custom layout) is not something that the Android API allows you to do for any menu item (sub menu or not) that is not on the Action Bar. If you must have a switch, you must use a different technique than using a menu.